# How do you access an array of structs of pointers to lists in C?

Tags: c, arrays, list, struct

```
typedef struct A {
   struct B *b;                           
} A;

typedef struct B {
int x;                                                  
struct B *next;                                  
} B;


A Table[10];
```

So I have those two structs and its supposed to be an array of structs A that holds pointers to other structs B(they are gonna create a list). I wanna access for example table[5]'s pointer. My code gives me an error "Incompatible types when assigning.I cannot make any changes to how the structs are formatted. Here is my code:

```
struct B* d_root;
d_root=Table->b[5];
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be just `Table[5].b` ?

Comment: That `Table->b[5]` means `struct B *b;` field is an array when it is not.
`

Answer (score 0):

you should use `d_root = Table[5].b;` instead of this `d_root=Table->b[5];`

you have an array of Table and to access `table[5]` you should use `Table[5].member` not `Table.member[5]`

also note `->` is not a right operator , look at usage of `->`:

```
struct *struct_name;

(*struct).struct_member;
```

since above program is little hard coding we can use:

```
struct *struct_name;

struct->struct_member;
```

but using operator `->` here `Table[5]->b` is wrong.
(note:Table->b is right , but it will point to first of array).

in your code this `Table->b[5]` means fifth element of array `b` in first element of array `Table`.

Answer (score 0):

The identifier Table is declared as having an array type

```
A Table[10];
```

So to access an element you have to specify its index to to use the pointer arithmetic.

```
d_root = Table[5].b;
```

or

```
d_root = ( Table + 5 )->b;
```

or

```
d_root = ( *( Table + 5 ) ).b;
```

In turn if the pointer `b` points to a dynamically allocated array then to select the desired element you can write

```
d_root = Table[5].b[i];
```

or

```
d_root = ( Table + 5 )->b[i];
```

or

```
d_root = ( *( Table + 5 ) ).b[i];
```

where `i` is an index in the dynamically allocated array pointed to by the pointer `b`.

To access a data member of the object pointed to by the pointer `b` you can write for example

```
int x = Table[5].b[i].x;
```

or

```
int x = ( Table + 5 )->b->x;
```